# Searching the Server IP on Client instead of inputing

Tags: android, sockets, ip, server

Server: PC

Client: Android

So my Client/Server app consists in opening webpages and executing a bot, everything is fine if I use only for a router, but I would like to be able to to connect in different places (different router/PC).
I was searching for "Wi-fi Search of IP" and got nothing.
Is it possible to give to the Server side a fix IP? like always 192.168.1.68?

Client Code

```
public class AndroidClient extends Activity 
{
    EditText episode;
    Spinner spinner1;
    String result;
    Button buttonConnect, buttonClear;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        episode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.episode);
        buttonConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
        buttonClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);


        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Animes);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.Anime, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);

        addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();


        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
    }


    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Animes);

        buttonConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);

        buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                MyClientTask myClientTask = new MyClientTask();

                myClientTask.execute();
            }

        });

    }


    public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            Socket socket = null;
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

            try {
                socket = new Socket("10.1.3.68", 8080);
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                        socket.getOutputStream());
                dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                dataOutputStream.writeUTF(episode.getText() + "-" + String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()));

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            } finally {
                if (socket != null) {
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (dataOutputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        dataOutputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (dataInputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        dataInputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        }

    }

}
```

Server Code

```
public class ServerSide extends Application 
{
    TextField textTitle;
    Label labelSys, labelPort, labelIp;
    Label labelMsg;
    CheckBox optWelcome;

    ServerSocket serverSocket;

    String message = "";
    String result;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        textTitle = new TextField();
        labelSys = new Label();
        labelPort = new Label();
        labelIp = new Label();
        labelMsg = new Label();




        labelIp.setText(getIpAddress());

        VBox mainLayout = new VBox();
        mainLayout.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        mainLayout.setSpacing(5);
        mainLayout.getChildren().addAll(textTitle,
            labelSys, labelPort, labelIp,
             labelMsg);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(mainLayout);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 400);

        primaryStage.setTitle("One Piece");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        Thread socketServerThread = new Thread(new SocketServerThread());
        socketServerThread.setDaemon(true); 
        socketServerThread.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private class SocketServerThread extends Thread {

        static final int SocketServerPORT = 8080;
        int count = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Socket socket = null;

                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        labelPort.setText("I'm waiting here: "
                            + serverSocket.getLocalPort());
                    }
                });

                while (true) {
                    socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    count++;

                    //Start another thread 
                    //to prevent blocked by empty dataInputStream
                    Thread acceptedThread = new Thread(
                        new ServerSocketAcceptedThread(socket, count));
                    acceptedThread.setDaemon(true); //terminate the thread when program end
                    acceptedThread.start();

                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ServerSide.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }

    }

    private class ServerSocketAcceptedThread extends Thread {

        Socket socket = null;
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
        int count;

        ServerSocketAcceptedThread(Socket s, int c) {
            socket = s;
            count = c;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(
                    socket.getInputStream());
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                    socket.getOutputStream());


                //If dataInputStream empty, 
                //this thread will be blocked by readUTF(),
                //but not the others
                String messageFromClient = dataInputStream.readUTF();


                message += "#" + count + " from " + socket.getInetAddress()
                        + ":" + socket.getPort() + "\n"
                        + "Msg from client: " + messageFromClient + "\n";

                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            labelMsg.setText(message);
                        }
                    });
                    String string = messageFromClient;
                    String[] parts = string.split("-");
                    String episode = parts[0]; 
                    String anime = parts[1]; 
                    String OneP = new String("One Piece");
                    String Naruto = new String ("Naruto");
                    String Bleach = new String ("Bleach");





                    int EPnumb = Integer.parseInt(episode);

                    if (EPnumb < 10) { 
                        result = "00" + episode; 
                    }
                    else if (EPnumb < 100 && EPnumb >= 10) { 
                        result = "0" + episode; 
                    }
                    else { result = episode; }



                 if (anime.equals(OneP)){
                    try {
                      Desktop desktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
                      URI oURL = new URI("http://kissanime.com/Anime/One-Piece/Episode-"+ result);
                      desktop.browse(oURL);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    }}


                    else {
                        try {
                              Desktop desktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
                              URI oURL = new URI("http://kissanime.com/Anime/Naruto-Shippuuden/Episode-"+result);
                              desktop.browse(oURL);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                              e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                    }





            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ServerSide.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } finally {




                if (socket != null) {
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(ServerSide.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }

                if (dataInputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        dataInputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(ServerSide.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }

                if (dataOutputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        dataOutputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(ServerSide.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private java.lang.String parseInt(java.lang.String episode) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

    private String getIpAddress() {
        String ip = "";
        try {
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface
                .getNetworkInterfaces();
            while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
                NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces
                    .nextElement();
                Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface
                    .getInetAddresses();
                while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress.nextElement();

                    if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                        ip += "SiteLocalAddress: "
                            + inetAddress.getHostAddress() + "\n";
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServerSide.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 

        return ip;
    }

    public DataInputStream String(String string) {



        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ServerSocket(int port, int backlog, InetAddress bindAddr)`

Constructs a new ServerSocket instance bound to the given localAddress and port.